# Jquery Find elements with an attribute inside it´s parent table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form validation code that detects all DOM elements with the attribute "validate". Which is called pressing the 'submit' button:

```
$('*[validate]').each(function () {/*validation goes here*/});
```

This works perfectly fine.

But also I have two tables, each one has it's own input element with the validate attribute in it and a 'submit' button.

```
<!-- First Table -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" validate /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="validate function call here"/></td>
    </tr>
<table>

<!-- Second Table -->
<table>
    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" value="" validate /></td>
         <td><input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="validate function call here"/></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

How can I validate only the elements that is in the same parent table of the 'submit' button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$(this)` is the submit button inside the handler

```
$(this).closest('table').find('[validate]').each(function () {/*validation goes here*/});
```

`closest` will traverse up to the *owning* `table` and `find` will search only within that `table`

Comment: `*` is useless here, but whatever. Since I see `onclick` attribute in original HTML, which doesn't presage anything good, here is [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/kast1rrm/) of "how it can be".